# Firebase PHP CURL Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, firebase, firebase-security

I currently building a small chat using Firebase and PHP. This, I thought, would be a good learning project for Firebase, and so far I am very happy with it!

However, I have hit a wall. I am not sure how I can implement an authentication system to Firebase via PHP. It's quite specific what I need the authentication system to do:

To be able to use the chat, the user must login using my custom php login system. Then once they are logged in, they will also authenticate to be able to read/write in the chat.

I couldn't really understand how this (if even) is possible with PHP, using CURL.

In my `__construct` function in have the following:

```
require('/libs/FirebaseLib.php');
$this->firebase = new fireBase('https://<url>.firebaseio.com');

require('/libs/JWT.php');
require('/libs/FirebaseToken.php');
$tokenGen = new Services_FirebaseTokenGenerator('<firebase-secret>');
$this->authtoken = $tokenGen->createToken(
    array(
        'id' => $this->userid
    )
);
```

How would I authenticate with Firebase to let the user be able to read/write in my chat and not allow non authenticated user to read/write?
Note: I have not done anything to the Firebase security rules - this is part of my question.

I've looked at the documentation, I might just be very thick, but I couldn't really find what I was looking for.

Hope anyone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I have intentionally not been using javascript for my chat, apart from ajax calls to my php script which then relays it to Firebase after I have done what I want to do with the user's messages.

**EDIT 2:** Added links to the used libraries: "[Firebase Token Generator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-php)" and "[Firebase PHP Client](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/master/firebaseTest.php)"

**EDIT 3:** My current code looks like this: ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073328/firebase-get-data-via-rest-api-php-curl))

**__construct:**

```
$this->authtoken = JWT::encode(
    array(
        'admin' => true,
        'debug' => true,
        'v' => 0,
        'iat' => time(),
        'd' => array('user' => 'admin')
    ),
    '<secret>',
    'HS256'
);
```

**New Message Function:**

```
$response = $this->firebase->set('/chat.json?auth=' . $this->authtoken, array(
    'message' => array(
        'username' => 'Test',
        'time' => time(),
        'string' => 'Hello World!'
    )
));
```

However it returns: `{ "error" : "invalid_token: Could not parse auth token." }`. I basically want to get permission as the administrator. I have tried just using the Firebase secret as the auth, but its returns the same error.

**Rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.username == 'admin'",
    ".write": "auth.username == 'admin'"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general workflow would be:

1. After user has authenticated with your custom login system, generate a Firebase auth token in your server-side PHP code.  (it looks like you got this far with the code snippet you pasted).
2. Pass that token back to the client.
3. Have the client call firebase.auth(<token>); to authenticate to Firebase using your server-generated token.
4. Use security rules to restrict what the client can read/write, depending on the contents of their auth token.

For a simple scenario where you just want to allow all Firebase access if they're authenticated, you could just have security rules like:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
     }
}
```

This would give authenticated users read/write access to your whole Firebase.  You probably want to lock it down more than that though (i.e. only give them read/write access to certain parts of the Firebase).  Check out our [Security Quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html) for a walkthrough on how auth and security rules work.

If this doesn't help, perhaps you can elaborate on which part you're getting stumped at.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I just about got it - How would one do the firebase.auh(<token>); using php/curl? I can see that this can be done with JS, but is it possible with PHP/Curl?

Comment: Or did I misunderstand you, and what I need to do is run the authentication via JS?

Comment: Are you using firebase.js at all?  When you said chat, I assumed it was something like our chat example (https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example/chat) but maybe you're doing something different?

If you're using the REST API from the client instead (i.e. doing ajax GETs/PUTs), you can still use the authentication token, but instead of calling firebase.auth(), you'll need to append ?auth=<token> to your REST requests.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am indeed trying to use the REST API. I will update my OP in 1 min with more info

Comment: OP updated. Thanks Michael, your help so far has really been useful and I really appreciate it!

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with the firebase-php client.  It automatically appends .json to the end of the URL which, with your code, ends up appending .json to the end of the auth token, making it invalid.  I opened an issue to suggest that firebase-php should support auth.  https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/issues/1

For now, you'll need to either make the REST requests directly, or modify firebase-php.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, I will give it a show. Really appreciate the help. Will mark this as the best answer :). Tested with my amends to the library and it works.