# firebase gives me permission denied when using php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-security

I'm trying to write to a firebase with php using REST and i keep getting permission denied

I'm using the test file like this:

```
$url = 'https://my.firebase.url/';
$atoken = '?auth=MY FIREBASE SECRET';

$fb = new fireBase($url);

$todos = array(
        'name' => 'Pick the milk',
        'priority' => 1
        );

$todoPath = '/test/test';

printf("Database: %s\n", $url);

printf("Sending data to %s\n", $todoPath);
$response = $fb->set($todoPath, $todos.$atoken);
printf("Result: %s\n", $response);

printf("Reading data from %s\n", $todoPath);
$response = $fb->get($todoPath);
printf("Result: %s\n", $response);
```

I have rules set up that only a specific authorized user "me" the admin can write to the the firebase but anyone can read from in. This was fine when the code was in Javascript because I would log in and be authorized. But now it's in php and I thought the "SECRET" would make that work or at lease I was lead to believe that by the firebase DOCS.

So what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

So I changed the:

```
$atoken = '?auth=MY FIREBASE SECRET';
```

to be

```
$atoken = '.json?auth=MY FIREBASE SECRET';
```

and I put it here:

```
printf("Sending data to %s\n", $todoPath.$atoken);
    $response = $fb->set($todoPath.$atoken, $todos);
    printf("Result: %s\n", $response);

    printf("Reading data from %s\n", $todoPath.$atoken);
    $response = $fb->get($todoPath.$atoken);
    printf("Result: %s\n", $response);
```

Now I get this Error:

```
04Database: https://MYDATABASE/ Sending data to /test/test.json?auth=MY FIREBASE SECRET Result: { "error" : "invalid_token: Could not parse auth token." } Reading data from /test/test.json?auth=MY FIREBASE SECRET Result: { "error" : "invalid_token: Could not parse auth token." }
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more about what your security rules look like? Rules checking for specific attributes in the `auth` variable will fail since you're using the Firebase auth. token directly and not an authentication token with a specific payload. However, any rules with `(auth != null)` will pass. Alternatively, you could generate an auth. token with `admin: true` that will let you bypass security rules entirely.

Comment: This is my security rules:  {
  "rules": {
    "games":{
      ".read": "auth.email !== 'null'",
      ".write": "auth.email == 'my@email.address'", 
      },
    "users":{
     "$userid": {
      ".read": "'' + auth.id == $userid",
      ".write": "'' + auth.id == $userid"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Based on your new error, I would guess that the auth token is a) not the correct one or b) getting escaped. Also, considering that firebase-php is using a PUT op via curl, I think you would be better off putting the auth token into $todos (the parameters) rather than on the URL.

Comment: I tried putting it in the array like you said 'auth' => 'TOKEN' I get permission denied. I tried it like this '.json?auth'=>'TOKEN' I get can't parse the json error . The soken is just my simple auth that I copy and pasted from within firebase.

Comment: I'm using under Firebase > AUTH> 'FIREBASE SECRETS' Is this not the token I'm supposed to use? I tried to use the custom token generator but I'm getting error with the php code I downloaded from git hub. Oh and I changed my rules to auth !== null and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that unofficial PHP / Firebase library does not currently support authentication, (see https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/issues/1 and [stackoverflow.com/questions/15953505/firebase-php-curl-authentication/15953974](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953505/firebase-php-curl-authentication/15953974).

I would recommend forking the project and adding a `.auth` method which hangs on to your token and automatically adds it to each request after the addition of `.json` on https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/master/firebaseLib.php#L63. Don't forget to submit a pull request to improve that library for others!

Comment: I've now forked the project and submitted a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

The REST spec looks like it allows this. I read it the same as you.

What is the exact error you're getting? Have you verified in Forge's simulator that you can perform these exact ops?

As for your PHP code, one thing stands out:

You have `$response = $fb->set($todoPath, $todos.$atoken);`

You are concatenating $todos (an array) with $atoken (a string), which isn't going to work. Did you mean to use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) or [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Looking over the [firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/master/firebaseLib.php) lib, you shouldn't be making those into a string anyway; it looks like you should be doing this:

```
$todos = array(
        'name' => 'Pick the milk',
        'priority' => 1,
        'auth' => MY_FIREBASE_SECRET
        );
$response = $fb->set($todoPath, $todos);
```

Or maybe

```
$todos = array(
        'name' => 'Pick the milk',
        'priority' => 1
        );
$response = $fb->set($todoPath.$atoken, $todos);
```